# Excel ActiveX CommandButton stopped working, won't respond to clicks

Tags: microsoft-excel, activex

I'm using Excel 2016 (store version) under Windows 10 on an MS Surface device.  All was good until a couple of days ago when activex buttons that I've created on several workbooks stopped responding.  I can run the macros manually (alt-f8), just can't use the buttons which is a real pain.

Anyone else experiencing this?  Would appreciate any advice.

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: I've seen this happen with certain Windows (Office) updates;  check what installed in that time frame & see if there is an issue like this associated with the update.

Comment: Thanks for replying Debra.  The only recent updates were to windows defender.

Comment: The weird things is that the buttons still respond to the defined accelerator keys but I just can't click on them.  Very annoying.

Comment: Weirder still, I've just found that if I keep clicking on the buttons, they eventually start to respond, and then they'll stop responding again.

Answer (score 0):

Got a resolution direct from Microsoft.  Had to find and delete my PERSONAL.XLSB file (with Excel closed) and then recreated the personal macros (which I had already copied).  Buttons are behaving normally again.  My macros are fairly innocuous so I have no idea why that file contributed to this problem.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/cant-click-activex-commandbuttons-in-excel-2016/f78cb87e-4df8-426a-b13f-4df8c03a7c47?tm=1547621541256